# How to extract archive via network

Tags: ssh, solaris

I have two Solaris servers. On server1 I have a file, `archive.tar.gz`. I need to extract it using ssh to server2.

So, I write the commands:

```
ssh server2 < archive.tar.gz | gunzip -c | tar -xf - -C /home/
```

But I got an error:

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

How to copy the file correctly?

Comment: Are you asking how you can login to server1 and extract the archive.tar.gz file and send it via `ssh` to server2?

Answer (score 13):

I believe you could do something like this:

```
$ cat archive.tar.gz | ssh server2 "tar zxvf -"
```

If you need to control the directory where it gets extracted to on server2:

```
$ cat archive.tar.gz | ssh server2 "cd /path/to/dir; tar zxvf -"
```

#### Solaris

Given you're on Solaris your version of tar is likely to not include any of the compression features that GNU tar offers. Fear not you can still do this command, we just need to decompose the cat `archive.tar.gz` into a command that can first uncompress the tarball.

Something like this should do:

```
$ cat archive.tar.gz | ssh server2 "(cd /some/dir; gunzip | tar xf -)"
```

Or this:

```
$ gzip -dc < sample.tar.gz | ssh server2 "cd /path/to/dir; tar xvf -"
```

Or this:

```
$ gunzip sample.tar.gz | ssh server2 " cd /path/to/dir; tar xvf -"
```

Comment: Solaris `tar` does not understand the `x` flag. So either use `gtar` (GNU tar) if it's installed, or better use `tar` and `gunzip`.

Comment: @Marco - thanks I completely forgot that those switches aren't present in Solaris' version of tar, let me reformulate it.

Comment: @Marco - see updates.

Comment: Why do you decompress before ssh? This seems better IMO: `cat archive.tar.gz | ssh server2 "(cd /some/dir; gunzip; tar xf -)"`

Comment: Every Solaris version ships with g(un)zip, zip support is just not compiled into tar.

Comment: @Marco - no reason, just was the first iteration that I di that worked so I went with it. I'll add your as well.

Comment: @Marco - shouldn't that be a ...cd /some/dir; gunzip | tar xf -)"?

Comment: Indeed, that was a typo, you surely need the pipe.

Comment: I'd also recommend decompressing only *after* you've transferred it -- no need to take up more bandwidth than necessary, after all.

Comment: Solaris 11 standard tar indeed has the 'z' (.gz files) and 'Z' flags (.Z files). On Solaris 10 GNU tar is *always* installed and is accessible using the 'gtar' command. So I don't really understand your posting ... unless OP is using Solaris pre 2005.

Comment: @unixhacker2010 - The last Solaris' that I used were 2.8, 2.9, and 2.10. The tar for the first 2 I'm pretty sure the tar did not include compression. Also the OP was showing the ... `gunzip -c | tar ...` pattern, so I was continuing with that, assuming that he needed it that way.

Comment: `$ cat archive.tar.gz | ssh server2 "tar -C  /path/to/dir -zxvf -"` is a bit more concise than using `cd`, but I'm nitpicking...

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ssh server2 < archive.tar.gz
> ```

You aren't passing any command to `ssh`, so it executes a shell on the remote side. The contents of `archive.tar.gz` are passed to that shell on its standard input, so it tries to parse it as a shell script. Hilarity may ensue, or not, depending on the content of the file.

It isn't clear in your description where you're running these commands. If you're on server1, have `archive.tar.gz` on server1, and want to extract the archive on server2, then pipe the archive to server2 and run the extraction command there.

```
<archive.tar.gz ssh server2 'cd /home && gunzip | tar -xf -'
```

Alternatively, log in to server2, mount the filesystem of server1 over [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html), and unpack the archive just like you'd unpack a local file.

```
mkdir /tmp/server1
sshfs server1:/ /tmp/server1
cd /home
gunzip </tmp/server1/path/to/archive.tar.gz | tar -xf -
fusermount -u /tmp/server1
```

Comment: wow, `sshfs` is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the archive into a specific existing directory without using `cd` command like this:

```
$ cat archive.tar.gz | ssh server2 "tar zxvf - -C /path/to/dir"
```

If you don't know if the directory exits you can use this:

```
$ cat archive.tar.gz | ssh server2 "mkdir -p /path/to/dir && tar zxvf - -C /path/to/dir"
```